# What's the best way to read a mathematical function f(x,y) command line argument?

Tags: c, math, command-line-arguments

From `main()`, I want the user to input a mathematical function (I,e: 2xy) through the command line. From there, I initially thought to iterate through the string and parse out different arithmetic operators, x, y, etc. However, this could become fairly complicated for more intricate functions, (e.g: *(2x^2)/5 +sqrt(x^4)* ). Is there a more general method to be able to parse a mathematical function string like this one?

Comment: 1. Use one of may existing math parser/evaluator libraries out there. 2. Implement a parser using lex/flex and yacc/bison (or some other lexer and parser generators) 3. roll your own parser

Comment: You have nice answers below, but first of all you need to define a [formal grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_grammar). Start easy with just the four operations and then try to read about lexers and parsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the most helpful ways to deal with parsing issues like that is to switch the input methods from equations like that to an RPN based input where the arguments come first and the operators come last.

Rewriting your complex equation would end up looking like:

`2 2 x ^ * 5 / x 4 ^ sqrt +`

This is generally easier to implement, as you can do it with a simple stack -- pushing new arguments on, while the operators pull the require pieces off the stack and put the result back on.  Greatly simplifies the parsing, but you still need to implement the functions.

Comment: If you want to roll your own, and you are somewhat new to CS, then this is is the only practical solution. Parsing something more complicated than an RPN parser is *way* more complicated than it looks. there are *many* pitfalls. If you are doing this for fun or a learning experience, the go ahead, writing an RPN parser and interpreter is a nice exercise. If you on the the other hand are only doing it because you need a math parser as part of some other project, then don't bother, use one of the many existing embeddable math or program interpreters out there.

Comment: OH, and if you *realy* want to write a math interpreter that accept an infix notation, having a working RPN parser and evaluator would be a very good first step.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is an *expression evaluator*.

A while ago, I wrote a complete C expression evaluator (i.e. evaluated expressions written using C syntax) for a command line processor and scripting language on an embedded system. I used [this](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/expression_evaluation.html) description of the algorithm as a starting point. You could use the accompanying code directly, but I did not like the implementation, and wrote my own from the algorithm description.

It needed some work to support all C operators, function calls, and variables, but is a clear explanation and therefore a good starting point, especially if you don't need that level of completeness.

The basic principle is that expression evaluation is easier for a computer using a stack and 'Reverse Polish Notation', so the algorithm converts an in-fix notation expression with associated order of precedence and parentheses to RPN, and then evaluates it by popping operands, performing operations, and pushing results, until there are no operations left and one value left on the stack.

It might get a bit more complicated is you choose to deal with implicit multiply operators (`2xy` rather then `2 * x * y` for example. Not least because you'd need to unambiguously distinguish the variables `x` and `y` from a single variable `xy`.  That is probably only feasible if you only allow single character variable names.  I suggest you either do that and insert explicit multiply operators on the operator stack as part of the parse, or you disallow implicit multiply.